# Webview javascript not working with javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to make the javascript work in android for this page:

http://test.swiss-impulse.com/scratch_card_game/index.html

But i have issues regarding the browser.

This is the parameters set for the webview:

```
webView1.setWebChromeClient(mClient);

webView1.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

webView1.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterfaceForTitle(this, mPasswordStrength, webView1), "HtmlViewer");

webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            if (url.equals(getContentUrl() + "addcomment")) {
                webView1.stopLoading();
                Intent addcommentIntent = new Intent(mContext, AddCommentActivity.class);
                addcommentIntent.putExtra("url", previousUrl);
                startActivity(addcommentIntent);
            } else {
                previousUrl = url;
                ((BaseActivity) mContext).showLoadingDialog();
                if (!urlStackList.contains(url)) {
                    urlStackList.add(url);
                }
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ((BaseActivity) mContext).hideLoadingDialog();
            if (url.contains("content/shows/") || url.contains("content/tips/")) {
                counter = 0;
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML(document.getElementById('" + mContext.getString(R.string.title_name) + "').innerHTML);");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML(document.getElementById('name_en').innerHTML);");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML(document.getElementById('name_zh').innerHTML);");
            } else {
                mStateBar.setShowTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.tv_drama));
            }
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
webview1.setWebChromeClient(mClient);
webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView1.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView1.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(httpCacheSize);
webView1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Am i missing some parameters to make this work on android webview ? I checked chrome browser and there it works with no problems, so i'm sure i missed something and cannot find what.

**EDIT:**

```
class MyChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mTargetView.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTargetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTargetView.bringToFront();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;

        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTargetView.removeView(mCustomView);
        mCustomView = null;
        mTargetView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // For Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        TvDramaActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Chooser"), 100);
    }

    // For Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    // For Android > 4.1
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
    }
}

public boolean inCustomView() {
    return (mCustomView != null);
}

public void hideCustomView() {
    mClient.onHideCustomView();
}
```

Comment: are there any errors or warnings in LogCat

Comment: Add webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

Comment: no errors or warnings

Comment: webView1.setWebChromeClient(mClient); i have that already. I will edit post to see my webchromeclient

Comment: Please paste your complete code for webview

Comment: I will try the code form my end and let you know.

Comment: You can ignore the webviewclient and javascript interface for the scratchcard test page

Comment: First link its the same as my settings, and in second i tried with DOM Storage enabled. Same issue. Javascript works on webview. The problem is that this kind of page/javascript doesn't work as intended like in the Chrome client from google.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

In your WebView Activity class :

```
WebView webView1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);

    webView1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView1.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    webView1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView1.loadUrl("http://test.swiss-impulse.com/scratch_card_game/index.html");
   }
```

Your layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in manifest file.

Hope this helps.Thanks.

Comment: Does the page scratches? I mean is there a picture if u scratch the blue area ?

Comment: You can check this from your end too.

Comment: its wierd because for me it doesn't work. Can you tell me what Android version you where testing ? (Im testing on android 4.3)

Comment: I am testing on Android 4.4 HTC One.

Comment: @Tazz Please check it on real device.It will not run in emulator.

Comment: yep. Im testing on Samsung S3 - 4.3. Genymotion emulator runs well, but this time im trying on real device just to be sure.

Comment: I checked on Samsung S3 4.3os and it does not work but works great in HTC One 4.4 os.

Comment: 03-28 12:02:26.514: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(25979): blockWebkitDraw
03-28 12:02:26.514: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(25979): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse

Comment: Thats the error when i try to scratch. I will test on a Nexus 4 with 4.4.2 and a Samsung S with 2.3 to see if i have different results

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409632/android-4-3-and-phonegap-cant-tap-link

Comment: From what i see this is a problem only in a couple of android version. It was reported that in 4.1 it was not working as well

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will report to the web team to check it.

Comment: No luck ... from what i see is a problem on android 4.1,4.2 and 4.3 didn't try on 4.0

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
//support JavaScript
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```